# Top margin property isn't respected when adding a LinerLayout into another LinearLayout

Tags: android

I'm trying to add this child `LinearLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Beautiful star-shaped spillway, Kechut Reservoir, Jermuk, Armenia"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

into this parent `LinearLayout`:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#F1F1F1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tiles"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I add this dynamically using the `Inflater` so there can be multiple items in my parent `LinearLayout`. I'd like to have spacing between the children so I've added property `android:layout_marginTop="50dp"` but this property doesn't get respected.

My children show up without any spacing between them. How I can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe because you are using "fill_parent" in the height of your children, try to change this to "wrap_content"

Comment: move android:layout_marginTop="50dp" from the layout to the textview

Comment: I just tried changing the `android:layout_height` of the child `LinearLayout` to `wrap_content` and it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find another way of doing this other than nesting the child `LinearLayout` inside another `LinearLayout` and adding the `marginTop` property to that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case it might work better with padding. I've experienced that when you don't limit your height or width of your layout padding tends to give better results (sometimes).